# Aggregating data using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have the following data similar to the below:

**Table 1**

```
Colour  Make
Red     Ford
Blue    BMW
Blue    BMW
Green   Golf
Yellow  Audi
Yellow  Audi
Yellow  Audi
```

**Table 2**

```
Colour  Make    Count
Green   Ford    5
Blue    BMW     1
Green   Golf    6
Orange  BMW     1
```

I would like to use pandas to aggregate the data in table 1, then either increment the count in table 2 if it already exists, or insert a new record if it does not exist. From the example data above:

**Resultant table:**

```
Colour  Make    Count
Green   Ford    5
Blue    BMW     3
Green   Golf    7
Orange  BMW     1
Red     Ford    1
Yellow  Audi    3
```

To complete the first aggregation step, I have:

```
df1.groupby(["Colour", "Make"]).size()reset_index(name="Count")
```

However, I'm not sure how to approach the second step. I'm inclined to opt for some kind of loop-based solution, but I've read that this is a no-no.

What would be the most appropriate way to get to the resultant table?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `concat` with `groupby` `size`

```
pd.concat([df1.assign(Count=1),df2]).groupby(['Colour','Make']).Count.sum().reset_index()
Out[127]: 
   Colour  Make  Count
0    Blue   BMW      3
1   Green  Ford      5
2   Green  Golf      7#check you expected output at this line 
3  Orange   BMW      1
4     Red  Ford      1
5  Yellow  Audi      3
```

Comment: I get an error when I use .Count. I've replaced with ["Count"] and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can align indices and structure, then use [`pd.DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `fill_value=0`.

```
res = df1.groupby(['Colour', 'Make']).size().to_frame('Count')\
         .add(df2.set_index(['Colour', 'Make']), fill_value=0)\
         .astype(int).reset_index()

print(res)

   Colour  Make  Count
0    Blue   BMW      3
1   Green  Ford      5
2   Green  Golf      7
3  Orange   BMW      1
4     Red  Ford      1
5  Yellow  Audi      3
```